# How to highlight on a richtextbox scrollbar background the relative position of a selected piece of text

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to highlight on the scrollbar background of a richtextbox the position of a selected text. Basically I'm using the richtextbox.find command to find text. I then highlight this text, so all fine there. But I'd also like to mark this position on the scrollbar background. So for a user, they would see they have to scroll down to say a red line on the scrollbar background  to find what they searched for. This would need to work for multiple different words, which can be in different places in the textbox.

An example of this is on tortisemerge on the Left hand side, it puts a little line in each place the code does not match the revisioned copy. So you can scroll to it quickly.

Comment: you want to draw on the scrollbar of richtextbox?right!

Comment: I want to draw on the scrollbar background to be more specific, not the bar itself.

Answer (score 1):

The RichTextbox doesn't expose a Paint event. So it is hard to paint on the actual Control surface. Instead I added a simple PictureBox directly next to the RichTextbox for a similar effect. With some simple math the position where to draw a line is determined and then DrawLine does the job.

#### Load event

Setup the bitmap here that we are going to paint on.

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.richTextBox1.Text = Texts.Lorem;
    // Create an bitmap 
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
}
```

#### Button Click

When we start a search, determine the position of the search text and then calculate the position to draw the line

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // find some text
    var index = this.richTextBox1.Find(this.textBox1.Text);
    if (index>-1)
    {
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
        {
            // calculate where to postion the bar
            var textpos = index / (double)this.richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            var position = (double) pictureBox1.Height * textpos;
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", index, textpos, position));

            // draw it
            gr.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 4), 0, (int)position, pictureBox1.Width, (int)position);
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Form Closed

Don't forget to cleanup the bitmap

```
private void Form3_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    var bmp = pictureBox1.Image as IDisposable;
    if (bmp!= null )
    {
        bmp.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When run this is what you get:

[image: demo of redline on position]